# Why can I not access the text of the UITextField?

Tags: swift3, uitextfield

I don't know why I can't access the text from the UITextField.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class MessagesVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextInput: UITextField! //Email Text Input

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextInput: UITextField! //Password Text Input

    var emailText: emailTextInput.text; //I get the error 'Use of undeclared type emailTextInput here.'    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

    } //Login

    @IBAction func signUp(_ sender: Any) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: , password: ) { (user, error) in
        } //Authentication Create User
    } //Sign Up

} //Class
```

This is the editor error I get:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: var emailText =  emailTextInput.text

Comment: Syntax of Swift for declaring variables is as follow  var/let nameOfVariable : TypeOfVariable = ValueforVariable

Comment: That didn't work, it just came up with: "Cannot use instance member 'emailTextInput' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are declaring variable with value of textfield. You can assign textfield value to that string variable.

you can write it like,

First declare it with,

```
var emailText = ""
```

Then you can assign its value inside `viewDidLoad` like below,

```
self.emailText = self.emailTextInput.text!
```